# Почтовый сервис

Tags: php, email

Стало интересно как работают такие как mail.ru, mail.com gmail.com и т.п.
То есть  как у них или как вообще реализуется регистрация почт. И можно ли это сделать одному самому.

Answer (score 2):

Можно,

Изучите RFC 5321 (SMTP), RFC 4511 (LDAP), RFC 3501(IMAP). Этого достаточно для старта... даже без LDAP. Потом пишете сервер(лучше на чем-то пошустрее, чем PHP), который отвечает согласно изученной спецификации.

Поверьте, регистрация юзера в этом одно из самых простых дел. В качестве исходников клиента можете покопаться в Squirrel mail. Это не образец для подражания, но их легко добыть.
P.S. без стеба: лучше потратить эти огромные усилия на что-то более нужное и менее распространенное.

Comment: Я не настаиваю. =) просто вам самому будет обидно, что почтой мало кто пользуется. Но в качестве тренировки - вполне себе полезное занятие

Comment: Есть, но правила форума всячески огораживают распространение контактной информации. Напишите в комментарии: за них не минусуют.

Comment: RFC 5321 (SMTP), RFC 4511 (LDAP), RFC 3501(IMAP) знать обязательно, так работает почтовый протокол.

Comment: LDAP нужен для адресной книги, на сколько я помню, которую можно на коленке собрать и иными способами. Другое дело, тогда клиент будет работать только самописный, никакие theBat уже просто так не подключатся. Так что для начала достаточно 1 - 5321 и 3 - 3501

Comment: Идея неплохая, но учтите, что для этого вам придется хранить пароли от этих систем. Позаботтесь о безопасности. С этого и предлагаю начать: напишите аналог keyring для паролей.

Comment: Идея не нова, в том же гугле мэйле и яндексе(чем пользуюсь о том и говорю) есть сборщики почты, могут собирать со всех ваших ящиков и сортировать как вам удобно....

Comment: И я себе сделал такой пол-года назад. Не пользуюсь им уже 5 месяцев и 3 недели. Возможно, если бы я запилил хороший дизайн (как, к примеру, в гуглопочте), то, возможно и пользовался бы, может даже сервис поднял бы.

Но получилась лишь неплохая тренировка по разбору писем, их заголовков, multipart-данных, да и вообще с декодированием вдоволь наигрался.

Comment: Продажники порой сами ищут толковых разработчиков точно так же, как и последние — продавцов. Разработчиков с их гениальными неповторимыми инновациями. Нет таких знакомых — на биржу стартапов.

Comment: Биржа стартапов мне не поможет. Я уверен, что ни один адекватный инвестор не будет инвестировать проект 14-ти летнего школьника.